# How can I force a Failure with parser combinators?

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

Say I have a parser def inside a larger parsing class like this:

```
def thing: Parser[Thing] = stringTerm ^^ { tLabel => repo.getThing(tLabel).get }
```

repo.getThing returns an Option[Thing].  Ok, let's say tLabel isn't found.  I'd rather not toss my cookies in an Exception.  Is there a more controlled way I can bubble up a failure during parsing?

Ideally it would burp up to this kind of top-level call:

```
    parse(freq, "johnny 121") match {
        case Success(matched,_) => println(matched)
        case Failure(msg,_) => println("FAILURE: " + msg)
        case Error(msg,_) => println("ERROR: " + msg)
    }
```

Can I bubble this up to either a Failure or Error?

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `^?` method (also called `mapPartial`) to apply a `PartialFunction` to the parser result, together with `Function.unlift` to convert an `A => Option[B]` into `PartialFunction[A, B]`:

```
stringTerm ^? Function.unlift { tLabel => repo.getThing(tLabel) }
// Or equivalently
stringTerm ^? Function.unlift(repo.getThing)
```

`^?` can also take an optional second argument to explain the failure:

```
stringTerm ^? (
  Function.unlift(repo.getThing),
  tLabel => s"Thing with label $tLabel not found"
)
```

Or you can use `>>` method (`into` or `flatMap`), to parametrize a parser based on the result of the previous one:

```
stringTerm >> { tLabel => 
  repo.getThing(tLabel) match {
    // `success` and `failure` create parsers that succeed or fail unconditionally
    // You can also use `err(message)` to fail with an `Error` instead
    case Some(thing) => success(thing)
    case None => failure(s"Thing with label $tLabel not found")
  } 
}
```